# Differential equation $y[1+(y')^2]=c$ with $c$ an arbitrary constant, verifying solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, fundamental-solution

How can I verify that $$y= \frac{c}{2}(2\omega -\sin(2\omega) )
$$ and $$y= \frac{c}{2}(1 -\cos(2\omega) )
$$ are both solutions of the differential equation $$y[1+(y')^{2}]=c,$$
 where c is an arbitrary constant. I'm just stuck at the replacement. I don't know what identities use to get c !!

Comment: To verify that these are solutions of the DE you don't have to 'get' $c$. Just differentiate and make sure that the DE holds.

Comment: But the answer is that neither is a solution.

Comment: My mistake. I didn't want to mean "find c". I also differentiate the proposed functions but I can't simplify successfully to see if DE holds or not.

Answer (score 1):

For the second solution, you have:
$$y= \frac{c}{2}(1 -\cos(2\omega) )$$
$$\implies y'=c \sin (2\omega)$$
Plug that in the equation and see if the equality holds. 
$$y[1+(y')^{2}]=c,$$
$$(1 -\cos (2\omega) )(1+c^2 \sin ^2 (2\omega))=2$$
$$.........$$
This must hold for any $\omega$. On the other hand, you should have a different constant for the solution $y(x)$. C is already in the differential equation.

Comment: I already tried. Maybe there is something I'm not seeing.

Comment: The equality does nort hold it means the solution you provided does not solve the differential equation. @charesp

Comment: Take for example $y'=e^x$ then $y=e^x+c $ is a solution for any $x$ and any c ...Thats why it's a solution of the differential equation $y'=e^x$